# How to create collect function generality

Tags: maple

I have a problem in maple, someone can help me.

I want to write collect function generality in maple. Example, i have

f := a(ak+bk+c)+b(bk+ck+a)+c(ak+ck+b)

I call gcollect(f,a^2+b^2+c^2) then we get

k(a^2+b^2+c^2)+abk+ack+bck+ab+ac+bc,

or gcollect(f,a^2+b^2) then we get

k(a^2+b^2)+kc^2+abk+ack+bck+ab+ac+bc.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to start with..

```
restart:

gcollect:=(expr,t)->
           thaw(collect(algsubs(t=freeze(t),
                        expand(expr)),freeze(t),_rest)):

f := a*(a*k+b*k+c)+b*(b*k+c*k+a)+c*(a*k+c*k+b):

gcollect(f, a^2+b^2+c^2);

gcollect(f, a^2+b^2+c^2, expand);

gcollect(f, a^2+b^2);

gcollect(f, a^2+b^2, expand);
```

Comment: I will try. Thanks you very much.